# How to customize the SplashScreen?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to make the SplashScreen as data binding pictures, how to do？

[image: this page]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should change the SplashScreen image under the Assets folder to an image of your choice instead of the square.

The second step is to create an "Extended splash screen", which is a new page on which you can show any picture you want (fixed or with data binding).

The most important piece of code is telling the App to switch to this screen instead of your first real page. `ExtendedSplash` is the name of your new page.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
    {
        bool loadState = (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
        ExtendedSplash extendedSplash = new ExtendedSplash(args.SplashScreen, loadState);
        Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
    }

    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

There's some additional code to position your image on screen resizes etc. You can follow [this step-by-step guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-a-customized-splash-screen) to create the `ExtendedSplash` page.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add a blank page with an image control, and customize its content as you like. Show this page before the MainPage and then navigate to MainPage after some time (say 3 seconds). This way you have a full degree of freedom and access to this page. It is called Extended Splash Screen.

I hope that helps.